# How would I make an unban command that can use the users ID or the name#discriminator

Tags: discord, discord.py

I would like people to be able to unban using either an ID / member.mention (discord.Member object auto does it) but also an option for user name and discriminator if they input that instead. I've looked everywhere and I can't find how to do it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please include your code, approaches and errors you face. You may also take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

```
    async def _unban(self, ctx, *, member):        
        if "#" in ctx.message.content:
            banned_users = await ctx.guild.bans()
            for ban_entry in banned_users: 
                    member_name, member_discriminator = member.split('#')
                    user = ban_entry.user
                    if (user.name, user.discriminator) == (member_name, member_discriminator):
                      await ctx.guild.unban(user)
            return
        else:
            member = await self.client.fetch_user(int(member))
            await ctx.guild.unban(member)
```

This worked for me, your arg has a "#" in it it will use the member.split('#') to split it into the name and discriminator then check that against your guilds bans. If your argument does not contain a "#" then it will assume that its a user.id and try to unban them that way instead.